# createPaymentMethod of Vue stripe element not working in Laravel, TypeError: Object(...) is not a function error occured

Tags: laravel, vue.js, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, laravel-cashier

createPaymentMethod of Stripe not working in Laravel and Vue stripe element. Here is my code

```
import { Card, createToken, createPaymentMethod } from 'vue-stripe-elements-plus';

components : {
    stripeCard : Card
},

methods : {
    pay() {
        createToken({
            name : this.name,
            street_line1 : this.street,
            street_country : this.selectedCountry,
            street_zip : this.postalCode
        })
        .then((data) => {
            createPaymentMethod('card', {
                card: data.token.card.id, // token from createToken (without any params)
                billing_details: {
                    name: this.name, // cardholder name
                    email: this.email,
                    address: { // address fetched from algolia places
                        line1: this.street,
                        country: this.selectedCountry,
                        city: this.city,
                        postal_code: this.postalCode,
                    },
                }
            }) 
        })
    }
}
```

But it shows error `TypeError: Object(...) is not a function`
I don't get where my problem is. Any  help would be appreciable. Thanks in advance.

I am using this package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-stripe-elements-plus

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create both a payment method and a token. The PaymentMethods API can be thought of as a newer version of the Tokens API (1). So you can simplify your code to:

```
  methods : {
    pay() {
      createPaymentMethod('card', {
        billing_details: {
          name: this.name, // cardholder name
          email: this.email,
          address: { // address fetched from algolia places
            line1: this.street,
            country: this.selectedCountry,
            city: this.city,
            postal_code: this.postalCode,
          },
        }
      }) 
    }
  }
```

*Note, I removed the `card: data.token.card.id` line entirely. This should be unnecessary since the library you're using adds a reference to the Card element for you automatically as you can see here:

https://github.com/fromAtoB/vue-stripe-elements/blob/ede16058193e2440dfd5a7cb7af17450d52e234b/src/stripeElements.js#L68

(1) https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods

Comment: Hm, it isn't obvious where that error might be coming from. It could be from the library itself in that case. if possible could you share a screenshot of the error from the browser console? The error message should also have a link to the line in the file where the error occurred - if you could share which line the error message points to it would help.